# Activity with two JSONClasses

Tags: android, json

I have an activity that suppose to use JSON twice. In the first time it works perfectly, but on the second time it seems that the JSON class goes directly to the onPostExecute function without activating the doInBackground function. This is the activity that calls the JSON:

```
public class Registration extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void regis(View view) {
        EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameTxt);
        EditText pass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PassTxt);
        EditText pass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RePassTxt);
        EditText displayName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DisplayTxt);
        EditText mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eMailTxt);
        CheckBox agree = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkAgree);
        TextView err = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);

        String uName = userName.getText().toString(), pss1 = pass1.getText().toString(),
                pss2 = pass2.getText().toString(), disName = displayName.getText().toString(),
                eMail = mail.getText().toString();

        if ((uName.length() > 0) && (pss1.length() > 0) && (pss2.length() > 0) && (disName.length() > 0)
                && (eMail.length() > 0)) {
            if (pss1.equals(pss2)) {
                if (agree.isChecked()) {
                    err.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
                    String str = "?uname=" + uName;
                    new JSONClass(this, 2, str, this).execute();
                } else {
                    err.setText("You must approve the use terms");
                    err.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                }
            } else {
                err.setText("The two passwords must match!");
                err.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            err.setText("You must insert values in every cell");
            err.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void checkExist(JSONArray ans) {
        try {
            int cnt = Integer.parseInt(ans.getJSONObject(0).getString("cnt"));

            if (cnt == 1) {
                TextView err = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.err);
                err.setText("User name already exists!");
                err.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameTxt);
                EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PassTxt);
                EditText displayName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DisplayTxt);
                EditText mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eMailTxt);

                String uName = userName.getText().toString(), pss = pass.getText().toString(),
                        disName = displayName.getText().toString(), eMail = mail.getText().toString();

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss yyyy-MM-dd");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

                String str = "?uname=" + uName + "&password=" + pss + "&email=" + eMail + "&disnam=" +
                        disName + "&dt=" + currentDateandTime;

                Log.e("log_tag", "Just for me: " + str);

                new JSONClass(this, 3, str, this).execute();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void openLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I removed unnecessary functions. This is my JSON class:

```
public class JSONClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONArray>{

    private String link;
    private int flag;
    private Login log = null;
    private Registration reg = null;
    private Context context;

    public JSONClass(Context context, int queryNo, String params, Registration regg) {
        this.context = context;
        link = "http://pickupfriend.fulba.com/android_project/query" + queryNo + ".php" + params;
        reg = regg;
        flag = queryNo;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(link);
            post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "utf-8");
            arr = new JSONArray(result);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return arr;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        switch (flag) {
            case 1:
                log.getResults(result);
                break;
            case 2:
                reg.checkExist(result);
                break;
            case 3:
                reg.openLogin();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

At first I activate the regis function that works perfectly with the json class. Afterwards it suppose to activate checkExist if the cnt parameter is 0, which is 0. Then it is suppose to activate the json class again but it seems that it goes directly to openLogin function without going to the php file and activating it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try to catch the specific Exceptions and print their error codes. Then post the logcat output

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was the space on the date I sent, I changed it with %20 and it worked. But now the date becomes empty and become 0000-00-00 00:00:00. How to change my php file so it could have the datetime as well? THis is the code inside my php file that connects to the date: $date = $_GET['dt'];

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO User
VALUES (NULL, '$uName', '$pass', '$mail', '$disName', 0, '$date')");